# Display div between navbar logo and navbar toggle in collapsed mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to put a search form between the navbar logo and the navbar toggle in collapsed mode, like this :
[image: Screenshot with correct design]

But I always get the following result :
[image: Screenshot with actual design]

I'm not having any problem when the navbar is expanded (not collapsed). Is there a way to make this work? Here's my code.

```
<header class="container navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
  <!-- First row, includes logo and search form -->
  <div class="navbar-header" style="width:100%;">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <a href="/" id="logo" class="navbar-brand">Le Collectif</a>

    <div class="navbar-left navbar-slogan-container">
      <div class="navbar-slogan hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <p>Slogan</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-right">
      <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recherche" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Second row, regular menu -->
  <nav class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I tried putting the div with the search form before the button, but it doesn't change anything. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have additional css because its working as expected so far? for this `id="logo" class="navbar-brand"`

Answer (score 0):

Answering here if anyone else has the same problem. Turns out this part of the code

```
<div class="navbar-left navbar-slogan-container">
  <div class="navbar-slogan hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <p>Slogan</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

was the cause of the problem. When rendered, even though the div had a width of 0px, some css put the height to 50px and somehow caused the navbar-right div to go on the second line. Putting hidden-xs and hidden-sm on the container div fixed the problem.